# Detecting the slide direction with javascript

Tags: javascript, google-closure-library

Looking for a way to use TOUCHEND, TOUCHSTART events to allow the user to scroll through the pages with slide gestures. I don't know how to determine the direction(e.g. get the coordinates of the TOUCHEND and TOUCHSTART points to determine the direction).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceptually, you can do this:

1. Register event handlers for the touchstart and touchend.
2. On touchstart, you store the x and y coordinates of a particular finger in a persistent variable.
3. On touchend, you compare the x and y coordinates to the previously saved values.
4. if Math.abs(deltaX) is more than some min threshold and Math.abs(deltaX) > Math.abs(deltaY), then the gesture is left/right.  If xEnd is greater than xBegin, then you're moving left to right, otherwise right to left.
5. If Math.abs(deltaY) is more than some min threshold and Math.abs(deltaY) > Math.abs(deltaX), then the movement is up/down.  If yEnd > yBegin, then it's down, otherwise up.
6. If neither direction is more than the min threshold, then the gesture wasn't big enough to represent a slide gesture.

See [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/touchstart) for info about the data for the touch events.  MDN is always the first place I look for this kind of stuff.

Comment: See MDN for the [event data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/touchstart).  You will need a touch device to access the touch data.  You could test out the direction algorithm using the mouse, but you've have to use mouse coordinates, not touch coordinates for that.